# How do I access a table name from data grid view?

Tags: c#, sql-server, gridview

So I'm trying to cope with an app project in c#/mssql.

It is Windows Froms app.

I'm connected to db, I can show all the tables in my db in the form  onload, but i don't know how, or if I can do sth like: when these table names shows click on any and it will send the db name as a variable to function, which will show me the content of the folowing table. I've learned about cellclick event, but i still don't know how do i make it work.

So the code below works perfectly fine

```cs
DbClassShow showObj = new DbClassShow();

private void MyWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = showObj.Select();
    QueryView.DataSource = dt;
}
```

but I want it to show the content of the table, when i click on it, but I can't attach like clik event to table name, because when the app is not running i can't even see content of the data grid view.

What do I do in this situation?

Comment: How does your gridview look like? Do you already see all the tablenames in this gridview?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys for bothering, I've been trying this and had no clue, but finally I resolved it on my own! Here's what i did:

```
        dbClassTables showTab = new dbClassTables();

    private void QueryView_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int indexOfRow = e.RowIndex;
        DataGridViewRow selectedRow = QueryView.Rows[indexOfRow];
        DataTable dt1 = showTab.Select(selectedRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
        QueryView.DataSource = dt1;

    }
```

Created a new class with select method with parameter and it works, I'm gonna make it more valid using abstract class or interface i think, but yeah, that's it.

```
public DataTable Select(string tbl_name)
    {
```

> ...

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM {0}";
            string data = tbl_name;
            sql= string.Format(sql, data);
```